# Install old versions of Mysql, Apache2, PHP

Tags: 12.04, apache2, php, mysql

Is there a way to install old packages of the following versions:

```
apache2: 2.2.12

mysql: 5.1.37

PHP 5.2.10
```

on Ubuntu 12.04, i386, using `apt-get` or `dpkg`?

Comment: As an alternative, I would suggest you look into virtual machines or containers (LXC, docker, etc.) to setup a specific setup

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you should notice that apache2.2.12 has many [security vulnerabilities](http://www.cvedetails.com/vulnerability-list/vendor_id-45/product_id-66/version_id-82377/Apache-Http-Server-2.2.12.html)

Now in general you can downgrade a package version in Ubuntu, but you should notice that the version must be available in the software channels(your repositories). To show the available versions for some package run the command:

```
apt-cache showpkg <package-name>
```

Now to downgrade a package select the version you want then:

```
sudo apt-get install <package-name>=<package-version-number>
```

Now back to your case, I don't think those versions is available for Ubuntu 12.04.